# Scanner not breaking when reading a line from a Process' output stream

Tags: java, process

I am making a program that runs multiple processes, and one of them is a Java program.

Just say I have a java program that looks like this in a file Foo

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

And then I have the program

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Foo");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
while(scan.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
System.out.println("done");
scan.close();
```

When I run it, it just prints `done`, and not the `Hello World!` that should be read from the Process. How would I do this?

Comment: I assume the problem is that `p.getInputStream()` should be `p.getOutputStream()`..

Comment: No actually. `p.getInputStream()` gets the input stream that reads from the output stream of the process

Comment: Oh, well that's confusing. I have no idea then :P

Comment: Yeah. I have been programming in Java for 3 1/2 years, and this problem is still impossible for me to understand

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I put `Foo.java` with your first code and `Main.java` with your second code in the same folder, compile them both and run `java Main`, it runs as expected. Are the `.class` files in the same folder? Try using an absolute path.

Comment: @bcsb1001 They are in the same directory. The program runs correctly, I just don't get anything from it

Comment: @MrYurihiredstone Have you tried also printing the contents of `p.getErrorStream()`? That should tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either also handle the process' error stream, or simply redirect that to the stream you're already reading via the ProcessBuilder API.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.command("java Foo");
Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: One problem. If the command is a variable, how will I split it up because `builder.command()` is String[], not a String

Comment: For one thing, you can simply provide a single string as the command. Beyond that, it will depend on which platforms you're planning on. You're best served by consulting [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command(java.lang.String...)). Please note the general notes at the top of the page.

Comment: Nope. Just gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java test.ProcTest1": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`